# Gstreamer Periodically get the current capabilities from a stream

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I am ingesting a video feed from a camera and I want to periodically check if the capabilities of the stream have changed (resolution/audio/encoding(h264/265).

For this I added `connect_pad_added` signal to the `rtspsrc` and when a pad is available I use the pad to check for capabilities.

I use the same pad again in future to get the current caps. However the capabilities are not updating when the resolution changes.

Will the `get_current_caps` for the source pad not get the latest caps?

What is the right way to achieve this?

Here is a simplified version of my code in Rust

```
use glib::{Cast, ObjectExt};
use gst::MessageView;
use gst::prelude::{ElementExt, GstBinExt, GstObjectExt};
use gst::Pad;
use gst::prelude::PadExt;

use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[cfg(not(target_os = "macos"))]
pub fn run<T, F: FnOnce() -> T + Send + 'static>(main: F) -> T
    where
        T: Send + 'static,
{
    main()
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct SourcePads {
    video_pad: Option<Pad>,
    audio_pad: Option<Pad>,
}

impl SourcePads {
    fn update_audio(&mut self, x: Option<&Pad>) {
        match x {
            Some(y) => self.audio_pad = Some(y.clone()),
            None => self.audio_pad = None,
        }
    }
    fn update_video(&mut self, x: Option<&Pad>) {
        match x {
            Some(y) => self.video_pad = Some(y.clone()),
            None => self.video_pad = None,
        }
    }
}


fn typefinder_main() {
    gst::init().unwrap();
    let pipe_str = format!("rtspsrc location={} name=rtspsrc0 rtspsrc0. ! rtph265depay ! tee name=t t.! queue ! hlssink2 name=ingest1 target-duration=2 playlist-location=stream.m3u8 location=%d.ts ", "rtsp://admin:pass@10.0.0.12:554/");
    let pipeline = gst::parse_launch(pipe_str.as_str()).unwrap();

    let pipeline = pipeline.dynamic_cast::<gst::Pipeline>().unwrap();

   let mut source_pads = SourcePads{video_pad: None, audio_pad: None};
   let source_pads = Mutex::new(source_pads);
   let source_pads = Arc::new(source_pads);

    pipeline.set_state(gst::State::Playing);

    let bus = pipeline.bus().expect("unable to get bus");
    let rtspsrc = pipeline.by_name("rtspsrc0").unwrap();
    let mut src_pad_clone = source_pads.clone();

    rtspsrc.connect_pad_added(move |src, src_pad | {
        let new_pad_caps = src_pad.current_caps().expect("failed to get caps of new pad");
        let new_pad_struct = new_pad_caps.structure(0).expect("Failed to get first structure of caps");

        for x in 0..new_pad_struct.n_fields() {
            let field_name = new_pad_struct.nth_field_name(x).unwrap();
new_pad_struct.value(new_pad_struct.nth_field_name(x).unwrap()).unwrap());
            if field_name.starts_with("media") {
                let media_type = new_pad_struct.value(field_name).unwrap();
                let field_value = media_type.get::<&str>().unwrap();
                if field_value.starts_with("audio") {
                    if let Ok(mut x) = src_pad_clone.lock() {
                        x.update_audio(Some(src_pad));
                    }
                } else if field_value.starts_with("video") {
                    if let Ok(mut x) = src_pad_clone.lock() {
                        x.update_video(Some(src_pad));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    let pipeline_weak = pipeline.downgrade();

    //////// use depay to get the current caps ////
    let depay = pipeline.by_name("rtph265depay0").unwrap();
    let pad = depay.static_pad("src").unwrap();
    pad.connect_notify(Some("caps"), |pad, _pspec| {
        let current_caps = pad.current_caps().expect("failed to get caps from depay");
        let new_pad_struct = current_caps.structure(0).expect("failed to get first structure");
        println!("DEPAY CAPS={:#?}", new_pad_struct);
    });
    //////// use depay to get the current caps ////

    for msg in bus.iter_timed(gst::ClockTime::NONE) {

        match msg.view() {
            MessageView::Eos(..) => {println!("end of stream");
                match pipeline_weak.upgrade() {
                Some(pipeline) => {
                    if let Ok(mut x) = source_pads.lock() {
                        x.update_audio(None);
                        x.update_video(None);

                    }
                    pipeline.set_state(gst::State::Ready);
                    pipeline.set_state(gst::State::Playing);
                },
                None => {println!("Could not get the pipeline")},
            };
            }
            MessageView::Error(err) => println!("received an error e: {:#?}", err),
            MessageView::StateChanged(s) => {
                println!(
                    "State changed from {:?}: {:?} -> {:?} ({:?})",
                    s.src().map(|s| s.path_string()),
                    s.old(),
                    s.current(),
                    s.pending()
                );
                if let Ok(x) = source_pads.lock() {
                    match &x.video_pad {
                        Some(video_pad) => {
                            let new_pad_caps = video_pad.current_caps().expect("failed to get caps for video pad");
                            let new_pad_struct = new_pad_caps.structure(0).expect("failed to get first structure of caps");
                            println!("CAPS FROM BUS={:#?}", new_pad_struct);
                        }
                        None => println!("video pad not found"),
                    }
                }
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
    pipeline.set_state(gst::State::Null).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
     typefinder_main();
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`Pad::get_current_caps()` will get you the latest caps at any time but in case of `rtspsrc`'s source pads these caps generally don't contain the resolution and especially won't change if the resolution changes as they're based on the static SDP.

You probably want to check the caps on a pad further downstream, e.g. the source pad of the video decoder (or the depayloader or parser).

To get notified whenever the caps are changing you could use

```rust
let pad = video_decoder.static_pad("src").unwrap();
pad.connect_notify(Some("caps"), |pad, _pspec| {
  let current_caps = pad.current_caps();
  [...]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse @sebastian. I tried adding the src pad and connect_notify.. but connect_notify never gets called on change in resolution.

Comment: What's the complete code you're using now?

Comment: I have updated the question with the updated code under ///.  It seems to pick up the change when the pipeline starts but never gets a callback after/ when the resolution changes. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the caps of the depayloader are changing. It does not parse the bitstream for such information. If you add a `h264parse` afterwards, set `disable-passthrough=true` on it then you should get the caps changes on the source pad of the `h264parse` as you do it here right now for the depayloader.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Even after adding h264parse, it doesnt seem to detect changes in resolution. It seems to only detect changes in resolution when a decoder is present and I add the connect_notify to the source pad.

Comment: I also noticed that using h265parse with fakesink like here crashes the pipeline. `rtspsrc location={} name=rtspsrc0 rtspsrc0. ! rtph265depay ! tee name=t t.! queue ! hlssink2 name=ingest1 target-duration=2 playlist-location=stream.m3u8 location=%d.ts t.! queue ! h265parse disable-passthrough=true name=parser ! fakesink async=false`

Comment: How does it crash?

Comment: when I use the above pipeline with `connect_notify()` set on h265parse element, I get stack smashed exception. I am running 1.18.6

Comment: Can you create an issue about that at https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/new after testing with 1.20? Please also include a complete testcase to reproduce the problem locally.